# Add location and bcc/resource - Don't Update Location

Tags: excel, vba

I've written a macro in Excel to send calendar invites (appointments) via Outlook. The **recipients must be bcc'd** (added to Resources field).

I have text in the body of the calendar appointment. It appears that by utilizing the WordEditor in combination with bcc/resources, I get an alert pop-up before each send: "Do you want to update the location to...?"
[image]

I do not want to update/change the location, as it would get replaced by the recipient list, thus defeating the reason for bcc (recipients would see Location as the entire recipient list).

If I remove the code block that adds text to the body (starting with "Set ActInsp..."), then this alert does not appear, and everything else works correctly; however, **I need the text body with a hyperlink**.

gif of how to duplicate the "Update Location" alert manually.
[image]

Below is a working sample of the macro. The code block with WordEditor appears toward the bottom, right above `.Display.`

Be sure to add the Reference: Microsoft Outlook 16.0 Object Library (I failed to get late binding to work).

```
Sub SendAppointments_SingleEmail()

Dim olApp As Object
Set olApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
'Requires early binding (late binding not working):
' Go to the Tools menu, Resources. Add Microsoft Outlook 16.0 Object Library
'Because AppointmentItem does not use HTML, must utilize Word VBA
Dim ActInsp As Outlook.Inspector

'Static fields
emailFrom = "test@gmail.com"
emailSubject = "My Subject"
emailBody = "Body of calendar invite"
hyperlink = "https://www.register.com/"
emailLocation = "My Location"
appt_Date = #7/30/2019#
appt_Time = #3:00:00 PM#
appt_Duration = "90"

'Create Appointment and Send
Set myAppt = olApp.CreateItem(olAppointmentItem)
With myAppt
    .MeetingStatus = olMeeting
    .SendUsingAccount = emailFrom
    .Subject = emailSubject
    .Location = emailLocation
    .Start = appt_Date & " " & appt_Time
    .Duration = 90

    Set myResourceAttendee = .Recipients.Add("test1@test.com")
    myResourceAttendee.Type = olResource 'Add as a Resource/BCC

    Set ActInsp = myAppt.GetInspector
    With ActInsp
        .WordEditor.Characters(1).InsertBefore (emailBody & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & hyperlink)
        .Close (olSave)
    End With

    .Display
    '.Send

End With 'myAppt

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Instead of Closing the Object from `ActInsp`, Close the `myAppt` object.**

**So change this part of your code:**

```
With ActInsp
    .WordEditor.Characters(1).InsertBefore (emailBody & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & hyperlink)
    .Close (olSave)
End With

.Display
'.Send
```

**With:**

```
With ActInsp
    .WordEditor.Characters(1).InsertBefore (emailBody & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & Hyperlink)
    '.Close (olSave)
End With

.Display
.Close (olSave)

'.Send
```

Comment: Thank you so much for taking the time to answer my question. This is exactly what I needed. With a little more tweaking I was able to make the complete macro work as well